# trying to create the toggled menu bar with react.js but the code is not working?

Tags: css, reactjs

the problem is that I wanted a toggle menu and I created a hamburger apply css on it and set up the methods but its not working, there is no errors given

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './toggle.css';

export default class toggle extends Component {

    constructor(props){`enter code here`
        super(props);
        this.state={
         switch:false
        }

    }
    handleSwitch=()=>{
        this.setState={
            switch:!this.state.switch
        }
    }

    render() {
        let className='toggle-switch';

        if(this.state.switch){

            className='toggle-switch changes';
        }
        return (
            <div className={className} onClick={this.handleSwitch}>

                <span className="bars1"></span>
                <span className="bars2"></span>
                <span className="bars3"></span>

            </div>
        )
        }
}
```

Comment: probably best to not use `switch` as a property on your state object as `switch` is a key word in javascript. Best to call it something more explicit like `toggleFlag`

Answer (score 1):

[**`setState`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) is a function. Your handler should be

```
handleSwitch = () => this.setState({
  switch: !this.state.switch
})
```

Or better yet, when referencing the past state value its best to use a function

```
handleSwitch = () => this.setState( prevState => ({
  switch: !prevState.switch
}))
```

Comment: @john-ruddell: thanks for the edit, that's a helpful note - I forgot you could pass functions to setState().

Comment: yep! figured I'd just help fill out your answer a bit with more information :)

Comment: thanks but there is another issue came out, I tried to add another state and set it in the methods and call the events (onMouseOver,onMouseOut)in another div its not working properly.do you have suggestion about this

Comment: here I posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437175/whanted-to-hide-and-show-the-opacity-the-methods-is-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setState` as function and I recommend to practice binding `handleSwitch` in constructor to access states for clearly understanding how it works:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        switch: false
    }
    this.handleSwitch = this.handeSwitch.bind(this);
}

handleSwitch() {
    this.setState({
       switch: !this.state.switch
    });
}
```