# whanted to hide and show the opacity the methods is not working?

Tags: reactjs

the problem is once I set the state and run the code it works when I add the other conditions and other methods it is not working properly

I add the handleOpti method and handleCare method to and set the states again and call the events in the specific div but it is not working properly

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state={
    show: false,
    opticare:false
  }

  this.handleSwitch = this.handleSwitch.bind(this);
  this.leave=this.leave.bind(this);
  this.handleOpti=this.handleOpti.bind(this);
  this.handleCare=this.handleCare.bind(this);
}

handleSwitch=()=> {
  this.setState({
     show: !this.state.switch
  });
}

leave=()=>{ 
  this.setState({
    show: this.state.switch
  });
}

handleOpti=()=>{
  this.setState({
    opticare: !this.state.opticare
  });
}

handleCare=()=>{
  this.setState({
    opticare: this.state.opticare
});
    }

render() {
  let className='reading-friends';
  if(this.state.show){
    className='reading-friends visible';
  }else if(!this.state.show){
    className='reading-friends invisible'
  }

  let optiCaption='opti-care';

  if(this.state.opticare){
    className='opti-care visible';
  }else if(!this.state.opticare){
    className='opti-care invisible';
  }

  return <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img onMouseOut={this.handleCare} onMouseOver={this.handleOpti} src="http://newstate.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/work-opticare-colored.png" alt="" class="we-do-img we-work-img img-responsive grayscale"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: where the `className` declare in the `render` method should be used?

Answer (score 2):

```
You just need to add this to your code:

This way you bind the `className` depending on the `state`

    className={
              this.state.opticare
                ? "col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center invisible"
                : "col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center visible"
            }

 The full code:

       export default class BoardName extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          show: false,
          opticare: false
        };

        this.handleOpti = this.handleOpti.bind(this);
        this.handleCare = this.handleCare.bind(this);
      }

      handleOpti = () => {
        this.setState({
          opticare: !this.state.opticare
        });
      };

      handleCare = () => {
        this.setState({
          opticare: !this.state.opticare
        });
      };
      render() {
let addClass = this.state.opticare ? "invisible" : "visible";
        return (
          <div
            className={`col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center ${addClass}`}
          >
            <img
              onMouseOver={this.handleOpti}
              onMouseOut={this.handleCare}
              src="http://newstate.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/work-opticare-colored.png"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: First time opticare is false,when we mouse over on div handleOpti is triggered and opticare will be true, in this case  class "col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center invisible" will be added and when we mouse out handleCare method will trigger and opticare will be false and "col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 d-flex justify-content-center visible" will be added.